# Grub missing after BIOS Update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 21.04

Help,

My Grub is missing after my laptop performed a BIOS Update. Still scratching my head on how to restore it.

I've booted up with a live cd.

I can see my partitions:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   2.1G  1 loop /rofs
loop1         7:1    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop2         7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3         7:3    0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop4         7:4    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11588
loop5         7:5    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
sda           8:0    1  15.1G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1  15.1G  0 part /cdrom
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 222.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   612M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   977M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0 728.8G  0 part
```

Efimgr:

```
root@ubuntu:~# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Diskette Drive
Boot0002* USB Storage Device
Boot0003* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
Boot0004* Onboard NIC
```

I've mounted the partition:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /mnt/boot-repair
root@ubuntu:~# mount -v /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt/boot-repair/
mount: /dev/nvme0n1p6 mounted on /mnt/boot-repair.
root@ubuntu:~# ls /mnt/boot-repair/
config-5.11.0-25-generic      initrd.img-5.11.0-31-generic  System.map-5.11.0-25-generic
config-5.11.0-31-generic      initrd.img.old                System.map-5.11.0-31-generic
efi                           lost+found                    vmlinuz
grub                          memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
initrd.img                    memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic
initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz.old
root@ubuntu:~# ls /mnt/boot-repair/efi/
root@ubuntu:~# ls /mnt/boot-repair/grub/
fonts  gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg  grubenv  unicode.pf2  x86_64-efi
```

At this point I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: UEFI update often resets many settings to defaults. Doulble check all the settings like Secure Boot, AHCI, fast boot and any others you may have changed when you first installed. I keep a list. I looks like UEFI boot entry is missing. For new user easier to just reinstall grub either manually or with Boot-Repair. Or use efibootmgr to create new entry.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. I went through my boot settings in the BIOS and cloud manually add the partition in again.